# How to teleport a specific NPC to the player (Custom NPCs Mod)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

I'm using the Custom NPCs mod in MC 1.12.2 and I have the command to teleport the NPCs to the player

```
/tp @e[type=customnpcs:customnpc] ChaoticDuskMC
```

However, I want to teleport a specific NPC that I have. The one I want to use is called Freddy.

Is there a command that I can do that only teleports the "Freddy" NPC to me?

Answer (score 1):

```
/tp @e[type=customnpcs:customnpc,name=Freddy] ChaoticDuskMC
```

The name argument restricts the command to entities named Freddy.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer worked for you, press the check mark button next to my answer. Welcome to Arqade!